# Cannot click on the element ..not able to identify it

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<div class="navpage-header-content">
<form action="textsearch.do" role="search" method="GET" class="form-inline navpage-global-search ng-non-bindable" aria-label="Global Search" target="gsft_main">
<input name="sysparm_ck" id="sysparm_ck" type="hidden" value="052ab09a0fa90700fa38563be1050e0fea31866160e7a5e6e0fc925775df282f070903d6"><div class="input-group-transparent">
<input name="sysparm_search" id="sysparm_search" placeholder="Search" type="search" class="form-control form-control-search">
<label for="sysparm_search" title="" data-original-title="Search">
<span class="input-group-addon-transparent icon-search sysparm-search-icon"></span>
</label></div></form></div>
```

This is the HTML tag for the element.

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='input-group-addon-transparent icon-search sysparm-search-icon']"));
ele1.click();
```

But my script cannot locate the element and click it.

I tried actions , Java script executor , but I just cannot Click on the element.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to edit your question to properly format the code and HTML so that it's readable.

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML?

Comment: What u exactly want with that elemnt

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to locate the `span`, You should locate `input` tag to click on search `textbox`, it should be like this:

```
WebElement SearchBox=driver.findElement(By.id("sysparm_search"));
SearchBox.click();
```

You can also use the `xpaths` to locate it:

```
  //*[@id='sysparm_search']
  //input[@id='sysparm_search']
  //input[@name='sysparm_search']
```

Use this code for xpath:

```
WebElement SearchBox=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='sysparm_search']"));
SearchBox.click();
```

You can also use `name` to locate it

Use this code for name:

```
WebElement SearchBox=driver.findElement(By.name("sysparm_search"));
SearchBox.click();
```